# Initialize beans after application startup/on application event [spring]

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have following situation. In my microservice [**MA**] I'd like to initialise/destroy some beans after application startup, or based on some event. For imagination there is another microservice [**MB**] which holds the informations about *ContentStores*. After the **MA** startup I'd like to ask **MB** for contentStore entries and based on that I'd like to create that many beans as needed. There can be the event which will trigger storeCreated/storeDeleted and in this case I would need to destroy the bean.

I currently don't know which interfaces do I need to implement/classes extend so please give me some suggestions.

So let's start with [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) and event [ApplicationReadyEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html). With this two I know that **MA** was initialized and I can probably ask **MB** for list of stores.

In this place I can take advantage of event's [applicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html#getApplicationContext--) and create beans (each bean will have it's own qualifier - e.g. ID) and if needed autowire their dependencies.

But from this place I don't know how to add created beans to ApplicationContext.

The same mechanism should exists for application events, but in that case I can probably at first check if beans were created and if so, return them.

note: I'm using spring-boot 1.4.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a child application context? You could then refresh it to create the beans and close it to destroy them. Exactly how you'd create the beans would then depend on your requirements. Can you describe the beans that you need to create? Is there a fixed, known number of beans and you just need some configuration from your other service, or does the number of beans vary?

Comment: Hi Andy, the number of beans is varying and depends on second service. In basic there will be 1-n content stores and I need to instantiate them at the application startup or in time when new contentStore entry is created in remote service. In the time there could be the situation when contentStore is deleted, so I will need to remove that bean from application.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson can you please look at [this](https://github.com/bilak/spring-bean-initializer-test)?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to initialise/destroy some beans after application startup, or based on some event.

For this question, you can regist a bean by using `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to register a `BeanDefinition`

An alternative is use `@PostConstruct` in a bean - "The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization. "

For the application exit, you can use the application exit hook here - [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit)

Comment: When is the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor executed? Is the time at the starting of application? If so I can't use this, because I need this process also in running application.

Comment: @bilak It call it in the context `refresh()` phase, so it is possible to do it and then execute the `ConfigurableApplicationContext#refresh()` to load all the beans, then the backing bean factory will be overwritten and a new one created.

Comment: can you please look [here](https://github.com/bilak/spring-bean-initializer-test). when you execute mvn spring-boot:run you can see the problem. I'm initialising beans in ContentStoreInitializer. But when I try to access them in FileSystemContentStoreService I can't get them. I don't understand if am I creating and accessing them in right manner. Thanks

Comment: I've resolved the issue, however I think it's not cleanest solution. There could be a simpler way how to do that.

Comment: @bilak sorry, the weekend so I missed your message, if you got a better solution, please share it to us, thanks.